# How to use accelerometer for paint on a screen in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, accelerometer

I am new in iPhone development, I am developing an app in which I have to use accelerometer for painting on screen . Please help me out is this can be done-able if so help me.

Comment: Do you have any code whatsoever? Or do you really expect us to do the hard work for you :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the **gyro mouse**, 3 lines of code. Watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k), the gyro mouse is presented at 37:00-38:25.

So long story short, you need the gyroscopes ([CMRotationRate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMGyroData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009941)).