# How to get angle change using accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, angle

I'm trying to get the angle change of an android device around the Z and X axis of the device using the accelerometer.
(relative to the angle of the device at the first time the application started or the calibration was done)

now i know i should do it with the gyroscope but it isn't possible because of the gyro drift.
i have tried doing it with rotation matrix and the function getAngleChange() but it didn't work because that from what i understood this function gives the angle change i worlds coordinates and not in the device coordinates (which is what i need).

so it will be grate if some one could help me with this problem.

thanks.

Comment: "world coordinates and not in device coordinates" - a simple transformation from one to the other should do.

Comment: If you have gyroscopes you should use them, with the accelerometers you can only get a poor estimate of the change in the **tilt** angles. What is it you are trying to do? My problem is: the information you are asking for doesn't seem to be useful, with the only exception of the so-called [gyro mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13084404/341970).

Comment: hi duffymo, I've tried a simple transformation with no success can u explain to me how to do that (or point me for a good article) ,and also to which coordinate should i . 
and Ali, i want to do something like a joystick so unlike the gyro-mouse the pointer will move even if the device doesn't if it was moved and and stayed at the sme angle after it was moved (hope u understood).